# Assigning DataGridView_1 (DGV) to DGV_2 and DGV_2 doesn't update

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have successfully found an answer to every question I ever had since I started with VB.NET 2 years ago by trawling forums, but this time I failed, and I decided to join my favourite forum where I have always found the best answers. This one :-)

I am somewhat of a beginner, so load you flack-guns 'cause here we go...

In my main form I have a DGV (called "gridDisplay") to display data. This DGV is a read only one as it is only used to disply data, not to inteact with it.

I have any number copies of a class (called "TaskData") that holds data to be displayed, and the data to be shown in the main form is that of the active "TaskData" class.

I came up with the brilliant (I have my doubts now...) idea to let the TaskData class make a DGV as it knows what data is in it and how to display it, and then all I had to do in the main form was to set the DGV there to that of the Active TaskData Class (see code below)

```
With ActiveTask

    'Assign the active DataDisplay to the one in the main form
    Me.gridDisplay = .TaskData.DataDisplay
    Me.gridDisplay.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.AutoSizeToAllHeaders
    Me.gridDisplay.Refresh() 'Trying to make it update
    Me.gridDisplay.Update() 'Trying to make it update
    MsgBox("Row count: " & Me.gridDisplay.RowCount)
End With
```

Ok, so the DGV in the .TaskData.DataDisplay has one column and 500 rows. The One in the main form is set up with a default of 2 columns and no rows (set up in the designer)

After the code above, nothing happens visually in the main form. Still 2 columns and 0 rows. However, the text box says: "Row count: 500" And if I put a break point there I can inspect Me.gridDisplay and it has all the data that should be there. 
Why doesn't it show up?
Am I doing something unwise by assigning one DGV to another?

Any help would be much appreciated.
Any constructive critizism equally so :-)

Comment: you are only changing the reference in your class, which has effect on the existing one in the form's Controls collection. Are you trying to bind two views to the same data source?

Comment: Hi. I'm not using any binding as I am only unsing it to display data and I read somewhere that Binding was primarily to link from control to data rather than data to control. All my data is entered by writing to the row cells directly in my class, before I pass the control to the main form. - Cheers

Comment: I just had a thought... When the DGV is created in the designer, it is assigned using something like 'MainForm.Controls.Add(gridDisplay)' Is that link somehow broken when I do what I do? gridDisplay obviously has the new data (as MsgBox above shows), it just isn't displayed, so perhaps the UI looses track when I do the assignment?

Comment: You can't have two objects pointed by one reference. And changing the reference has no effect on the form whatsoever, the form does not care if you have an extra reference on its controls.

Comment: I guess what I was planning on doing was to have my designed DGV (gridDisplay) in there merely as to have a control name to use. I do not intend to point at two objects, I am happy to de-reference the original DGV and then point the reference to the new object, the DGV in my TaskData class. I reasoned that the original DGV object would be handled by garbage collection and the new one would be shown. The strange thing is still that "gridDisplay" will report 1 col, 500 rows and even says it has 4 rows displayed, although nothing changes in the GUI (2 col and 0 rows)...

Comment: Yes it is still in the form's controls collection, you did not remove it from the form. If you need to change its content, change in its datasource.

Comment: So, the control is still in the form (shown in the GUI), without a reference ("gridDisplay" is now pointing at my TaskData DGV) , and therefore, when I examine "gridDisplay" it is showing what I "expect" which is the data from my TaskData class. It is not showing the data in the form because the DGV in my class has not been set as a control of the form... I think I get it now :-) Thanks Sheng! PS. I have now switched to using a DataSet in my class and setting that to the DataSource of my DGV and it is working well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call the datasource again before
Me.gridDisplay.Refresh()
Me.gridDisplay.Update()

Something like this, 
gridDisplay.DataSource = dataset.Tables["your table"];

Comment: Hi @michelle, Thanks for that. I have ditched my original idea as outlined in my question as I could see the flawed thinking behind it :-) I am now creating a DataSet instead of a full DGV object, and so far it is working a treat and I don't have to worry about updating etc. Certainly some deeper insight into .NET for me, so alltogether a useful exercise :-)